# IIf with Field choices instead of Text

Tags: reporting-services

I'd like my IIf statement to use a field, rather than inputting text. Is that possible?

=IIf(Fields!Customer_Type.Value="Foundation","Fields!Sort_Name.Value","Fields!ESal1_Description.Value")

Comment: remove the quotes from the true and false part of the `IIF` statement. That should do it

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use what you have but remove the quotes from the true and false values

```
 IIf(Fields!Customer_Type.Value="Foundation",Fields!Sort_Name.Value,Fields!ESal1_Description.Value)
```